# Auto-versioning of static content with JBoss

Tags: tomcat, caching, jboss, auto-versioning

As per the Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files), I'd like to implement a similar auto-versioning system for a web app running in JBoss 5. Is there anything already out there to do this sort of thing, or will I need to write something myself? To be clear: **I am not using PHP.**

Not knowing much about PHP, I'm not sure what the Tomcat/JBoss analogs of PHP's `.htaccess`, etc. are. If I do have to write my own auto-versioning, where would I start? The principle is clear to me - rewriting the URL using the file's timestamp, but I don't know much about URL rewriting with JBoss/Tomcat.

---

### Update:

Combining the approaches recommended by [Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630885/auto-versioning-of-static-content-with-jboss/2667786#2667786) and [novice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630885/auto-versioning-of-static-content-with-jboss/3719518#3719518), here's what I ended up with:

**1.** Custom `<my:script/>` and `<my:style/>` tags, so I wouldn't have to see `<c:url/>` tags everywhere.

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="src" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<script src="<c:url value="${src}" />"></script>
```

**2.** Following fairly closely to novice's steps, but mapping `UrlRewriteFilter` to `/*` in web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**3.** Injecting a CACHE_BUST variable to every new session (more or less...), an application deploy    timestamp:

```
// On application deploy:
long CACHE_BUST = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

// later...
session.setAttribute("cacheBust", CACHE_BUST);
```

**4.** ...so that I can use these rules in `urlrewrite.xml`:

```
<outbound-rule>
    <from>^/static/(css|js|images)/(.*)$</from>
    <to>%{context-path}/static/%{session-attribute:cacheBust}/$1/$2</to>
</outbound-rule>

<rule>
    <from>^/static/\d{10}/(css|js|images)/(.*)$</from>
    <to>/static/$1/$2</to>
</rule>
```

---

Many thanks to [Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent) and [novice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136913/novice) for their help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following solution is better suited in production environment as you would be incrementing the version number for each release.

**Approach:**

- append the product release number(version number) to the js/css/images/static content urls in jsp files
- browser would cache (js/css/static)files with the url containing the version number
- when a new version is released, the jsp files will have the urls of js/css/static files with new version number, so the browser will make a call as it can't find the content for the new url

**Steps:**

- include urlrewritefilter.jar in the class path (get it from http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)
- update web.xml with the url pattern, for e.g,

  ```
  <filter>
      <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/v/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  ```
- update 'abc.js' in the jsp file, for e.g.,

  ```
  <html>
      <head>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/v/js/abc.js"/>"></script>
      </head>
  </html>
  ```
- write urlrewritefilter.xml, for e.g.,

  ```
  <outbound-rule>
      <from>^/v/(css|js|static)/(.*)$</from>
      <to>%{context-path}/v/updateVersionNumberHere/$1/$2</to>
  </outbound-rule>

  <rule>
      <from>^/v/updateVersionNumberHere/(css|js|static|images)/(.*)$</from>
      <to>/$1/$2</to>
  </rule>
  ```

  **Explanation:**

  **when jsp is served to client**

  - **url mentioned in the jsp:** /v/js/abc.js
  - **after applying outbound rule:** /contextPath/v/3.4.5/js/abc.js

  **when browser makes a call for js/css/static files**

  - **incoming url:** /contextPath/v/3.4.5/js/abc.js
  - **after applying rule:** /js/abc.js

**Points:**

- browser would catch the js files with url /contextPath/v/3.4.5/js/abc.js, next you deploy a new version of jsp files they might have the url /contextPath/v/4.5.6/js/abc.js, so the browser would make a call for js file instead of using the cached js file.
- version updating could be automated if you use maven or similar build tool

Comment: This looks very promising. Will test out ASAP. Might combine with @Pascal's server startup time suggestion.

Comment: That spelled it out beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to front your application with Apache HTTPD, then you could use a custom servlet filter or reuse the existing [Url Rewrite Filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). This filter is based on Apache's `mod_rewrite` and offers similar capabilities. In other words, it would allow to implement the same solution than the PHP one of the other answer.

---

> I've seen the URL rewrite filter before. Could you elaborate on how I'd use that? I'm really not clear on how I'd apply a filter to this problem, since I wouldn't exactly be calling a JSP/JSTL function wrapped around each included JS/CSS file, and I have no idea about how to get the date modified from a file that's in a WAR.

Well, the idea was to mimic exactly the "PHP solution" of the answer you linked to (let's call this option 1):

1. Setup the Url Rewrite Filter to rewrite any request to say `/css/my.123456.css` into `/css/my.css`
2. Implement a `Servlet` that would get a `File` object for a given resource inside the WAR and insert `File#lastModified()` in the returned path to that resource.
3. Invoke that `Servlet` from the JSP for the CSS.

---

Another approach (option 2) would be to append an unique query string to the URL of the static content, e.g. the server startup time:

1. Put the server startup time in the application scope from a [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) (say under the key `"key"`).
2. In you JSP

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/my.css?${key.startupTime}">
   ```

Pro: no url rewrite stuff anymore. Con: Less optimal (content will be request on restart) but acceptable.

---

While searching the web for some code that could help to implement the step #2 of option 1, I found Spring's [`o.s.w.s.ResourceServlet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ResourceServlet.html) that is doing something similar, you could look at its source code. But, while reading its javadoc more carefully, I realized that this servlet is actually exactly what you're looking for. Map it like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And set its `applyLastModified` property to `true`. My understanding of the javadoc is that it should do the trick. This is option 3 and this is IMO the best option if adding a dependency on this servlet in not an issue.

Comment: I've seen the URL rewrite filter before. Could you elaborate on how I'd use that? I'm really not clear on how I'd apply a filter to this problem, since I wouldn't exactly be calling a JSP/JSTL function wrapped around each included JS/CSS file, and I have no idea about how to get the date modified from a file that's in a WAR.

Answer (score 1):

We do the following in our web app:

1. Build process retrieves Subversion repository number and stores it in a property within the web application.
2. Build process also creates a directory structure for static assets within the WAR that incorporates this revision number: /assets/1234/styles/...
3. Filter/interceptor puts assets path (including revision number) into all requests as attribute
4. Jsp templates use this assets path attribute to construct URLS for assets

Comment: That's not that helpful. Like I said, I get the principle; I'm looking for implementation specifics.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything "built in" that specifically handles this issue.  What I described above is exactly our implementation, and works well enough for us.